# Is there a difference between Streaming and Download with Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Is there a difference between streaming video and downloading a video in the Firebase Storage?

Specifically, I have noticed that each media element upon upload has a 'Download link', but is that the same to the client as streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Storage doesn't support sophisticated video [streaming protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media#Protocol_challenges).  All it will let you do is send the contents of a file via a standard HTTPS link, but that's not what most engineers think of when it comes to streaming (which lets the end user set stream quality, adjust play rate, adjust play position, etc).

Comment: yeah.. basically what I am trying to pull off is snapchat/instagram eseque video streaming.. where it is as fast as possible

Comment: I did notice google cloud storage (which I kinda thought was the same thing) lists video streaming as one of their strengths. but i have no clue how to get started

Comment: Where in the Cloud Storage documentation does it suggest that it's good for *streaming* (as opposed to just video file storage and processing)?

Comment: not in documentation, but right on the use case (https://cloud.google.com/storage/use-cases/) says video streaming. although that could be misleading and could just be video file storage and processing..

Comment: do you have any recomendations on what one would use for streaming then? I've been trying to figure out some sort of solution in googles suite of products